# Computer boots to /dev/tty0 instead of /dev/tty1

Tags: debian, tty

I have two computers, both running Debian Bookworm and upgraded to the same degree with the latest software installed. Both machines are configured to boot to text terminals, which they need to do before starting X.

The problem is that one computer boots to `/dev/tty0` instead of `/dev/tty1` which means that the xinit command that works on Computer 2 doesn't work on Computer 1.

Computer 1's kernel boots to `/dev/tty0` with these permissions:

```
crw------- 1 ben  tty 4, 0 May 23 16:46 /dev/tty0
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 1 May 23 16:46 /dev/tty1
crw------- 1 ben  tty 4, 2 May 23 16:13 /dev/tty2
```

Computer 2's kernel boots to `/dev/tty1` with these permissions:

```
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 0 May 23 05:55 /dev/tty0
crw--w---- 1 ben  tty 4, 1 May 23 16:29 /dev/tty1
crw------- 1 ben  tty 4, 2 May 23 16:13 /dev/tty2
```

The command to start X that works on Computer 2 but not on Computer 1 is:

```
xinit /home/ben/.xinitrc -- /usr/bin/X :0 vt1
```

User ben has no permission on Computer 1 to access `tty1`, so X fails with a `no permission` message.

To start X on Computer 1, user ben needs to change the `xinit` command to use `vt2`, and navigate to `tty2` to run it.

The mystifying aspect for me is that `/dev/tty1` is not available on Computer 1.

Computer 1 shows the terminals as:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> gets `/dev/tty0`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gets `/dev/tty2`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> gets `/dev/tty3`

whereas on Computer 2 shows the terminals as:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> gets `/dev/tty0`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gets `/dev/tty1`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> gets `/dev/tty2`

In an attempt to boot to `/dev/tty1` on Computer 1, I added the kernel option of `console=/dev/tty1`. The machine froze with a blank screen and the flashing cursor at the top left. It needed a rescue-disk to rewrite the `grub.cfg` file and erase the option to be able to boot properly.

Systemd shows the same `active and running` output for `getty@tty1.service` on both machines.

My query is: how to configure the machine so that `/dev/tty1` appears on Computer 1, and thus have Computer 1 boot to `dev/tty1` instead of to `/dev/tty0`?

I ask here having failed to find an answer elsewhere.

Edits:
Thanks to all the respondents!

cat /proc/fb outputs the same on both machines: 0 nouveaudrmfb.

I guess I could script a change to ownership of tty0 and tty1 on boot but it feels like a workaround. No other machines here would need this.

Comment: On Computer 1, set the owner of /dev/tty1 to ben, and the owner of /dev/tty0 to root.

Comment: I guess the graphics hardware is different. What is the output of `cat /proc/fb`?

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity: why are you using the archaic `xinit` directly, and not `startx`? The latter would probably allow you to simplify the X startup command line, see `man startx` for details.

Comment: Yes telcoM, it is archaic and it's the result of historical use over many years here on a number of machines that all have had the same configs for a long time on debian testing so they've never been refreshed with a new installation and the configs simply persisted. I take your point about startx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device node `/dev/tty0` acts like a hard link to "whatever is the currently selected virtual console", although it is actually implemented within the virtual console driver code.

As a `console=` boot option value, `/dev/tty0` means "I want to use the usual KVM physical console (with its entire set of virtual consoles) as a system console". Like you discovered, a boot option `console=/dev/tty1` is not valid (on x86 hardware at least):

Normally `root` will own any logged-out tty devices, and a logged-in user will have ownership of their tty device assigned to them by the login process. A logout should return the tty device to the ownership of `root`. But if user `ben` has managed to get the ownership of `/dev/tty0`, that could mean they might be able to use it (e.g. by logging in over a SSH connection) to inject stuff into the session of whoever is logged in locally on any actual virtual console (`/dev/tty[1..N]`).

The ownership of `/dev/tty0` should never change away from root ownership.

Can you see processes running on `tty0`, with `fuser /dev/tty0` run as root? There should not be any normally.

Is there a `getty@tty0.service` defined? If it is, that could be causing the problems: `/dev/tty0` should never be used for regular logins.

Comment: fuser /dev/tty0 output 763, and cat /proc/763/cmdline is bash. fuser /dev/tty1 showed no output. getty@tty0 is "loaded and active" on Computer 1, but not on computer 2. It's clear now that /dev/tty0 was defined, and enabled by systemctl. I have disabled it and now the expected behaviour of booting to /dev/tty1 has reappeared. Thank you!